# How can i find memory leak or any gc issues using jmeter?

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

this is my first time to load test an application without using any application monitoring app in place. So now, im just using jmeter and its performance stats reporting capability. If I may ask, are there any ways wherein I can detect memory leaks , gc issues, or swapping with just using only JMETER?

Answer (score 2):

You can run any performance monitor in server while running the jmeter test.
Jmeter has a plugin which can be used to for the similar propose. Check the link below.

https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/

I would recommend running a Soak test rather then a normal load or stress test. Whrere in you load test the application for couple of hours.

Comment: Can i use perfmon while im running my jmx scripts via command line?

Comment: Yes you can run perfmon even when running the jmx from cmd